# How to load a javascript or css file into a BottlePy template?

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to return a html template with BottlePy. And this works fine. But if I insert a javascript file like this in my tpl-file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I get an 404 error.
*(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found))*

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Here is my script file:

```
from bottle import route, run, view

@route('/')
@view('index')
def index():
    return dict()
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

And that is the template file, located in "./views" subfolder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe it is the "rootPath/js/main.js" from the development server where it looks for my js-file?

The structure of the files is:

```
app.py
-js
 main.js
-views
 index.tpl
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried some sort of debugging, like printing out your root path and your js folder content?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, first, you need your dev server to actually serve `main.js`, otherwise it won't be available for the browser.

It's customary to put all `.js` and `.css` files under the `static` directory in small web apps, so your layout should look like this:

```
  app.py
- static/
    main.js
- views/
    index.tpl
```

By no means this exact naming and layout is required, only often used.

Next, you should supply a handler for the static files:

```
from bottle import static_file

# ...

@route('/static/:path#.+#', name='static')
def static(path):
    return static_file(path, root='static')
```

This will actuall serve your files under `static/` to the browser.

Now, to the last thing. You specified your JavaScript as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

That means the path to `.js` is *relative* to the current page. On you development server, the index page (`/`) will look for `.js` in `/js/main.js`, and another page (say, `/post/12`) will look for it in `/post/12/js/main.js`, and will sure fail.

Instead, you need to use the `get_url` function to properly reference static files. Your handler should look like this:

```
from Bottle import get_url

# ...

@route('/')
@view('index')
def index():
    return { 'get_url': get_url }
```

And in `index.tpl`, `.js` should be referenced as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ get_url('static', path='main.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

`get_url` finds a handler with `name='static'`, and calculates the proper path to it. For dev server, this will always be `/static/`. You can probably even hard-code it in the template, but I don't recommend it for two reasons:

- You won't be able to mount your app anywhere but under root in production; i.e., when you upload it onto the porduction server, it can be placed under http://example.com/ (root), but not under http://example.com/myapp/.
- If you change the `/static/` dir location, you'll have to search it all over your templates and modify it in every single template.

Comment: can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505256/static-files-in-bottle-py

Comment: @Anuj: I've answered your question.

Comment: @Helgi What does the `#.+#` expression at the route do?

Comment: @Lucio, the expression between the `#` is a regex (regular expression). The `.` character matches any character and `+` means any number but at least one. Therefore, the regex is matching any string that has a length of at least one character.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working approach of adding static files like CSS/JS in **Bottle** web project. I am using Bootstrap and Python 3.6.

**Project structure**

```
project
│   app.py
│   bottle.py
│
├───static
│   └───asset
│       ├───css
│       │       bootstrap-theme.css
│       │       bootstrap-theme.css.map
│       │       bootstrap-theme.min.css
│       │       bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
│       │       bootstrap.css
│       │       bootstrap.css.map
│       │       bootstrap.min.css
│       │       bootstrap.min.css.map
│       │       custom.css
│       │
│       ├───fonts
│       │       glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│       │       glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│       │       glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│       │       glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│       │       glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│       │
│       └───js
│               bootstrap.js
│               bootstrap.min.js
│               jquery.min.js
│               npm.js
│
└───views
        index.tpl
```

**app.py**

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, \
     template, debug, static_file

import os, sys

dirname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

app = Bottle()
debug(True)

@app.route('/static/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def send_css(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root=dirname+'/static/asset/css')

@app.route('/static/<filename:re:.*\.js>')
def send_js(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root=dirname+'/static/asset/js')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = {"developer_name":"Ahmedur Rahman Shovon",
            "developer_organization":"Datamate Web Solutions"}
    return template('index', data = data)

run(app, host='localhost', port = 8080)
```

**index.tpl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Bottle web project template">
    <meta name="author" content="datamate">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">        
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="../navbar/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./">Github</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Stackoverflow</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Welcome from {{data["developer_name"]}}</h2>
                <p>This is a template showcasing the optional theme stylesheet included in Bootstrap. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique by building on or modifying it.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--./row-->
        <div class="row">
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2017 {{data["developer_organization"]}}.</p>
            </footer>           
        </div>
    </div> 
    <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image: bottle bootstrap demo]

Comment: Thank you for a simple example. Depending on how you run `app.py`, using `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` may not get the correct path. For example, I am running a Bottle server as a daemon service where I set a `WorkingDirectory` that points to where `app.py` exists. Whenever I need the location for any python script I use this hack `sys.path[0]` as python will typically load the script's path into `sys.path` prior to launching. So to get your solution to work, I use:

Comment: `dirname = sys.path[0] + '/'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting the file `main.js` in the wrong location.

Note that this file path must be relative to the requested url, not relative to the path to your template. So putting it in a folder like `template/js/main.js` will not work.