# Static files not loaded in a Bottle application when the trailing slash is omitted

Tags: python, apache, bottle

I am serving a test file through apache using Bottle.

Following are my apache config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess temp user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /temp /opt/gridops/usage/temp/adapter.wsgi

<Directory /opt/gridops/usage/temp>
        WSGIProcessGroup temp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

`adapter.wsgi`:

```
import os,sys
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path = ['/opt/gridops/usage/temp'] + sys.path
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
import bottle
print "++"*10
import index # This loads your application
application = bottle.default_app()
```

`index.py`:

```
from bottle import mount, run 
from routes import app
from bottle import default_app
default_app.push(app)
#run()
#run(app=app, host='192.168.1.3', port=8085)
```

`routes.py`:

```
from bottle import Bottle , run,route,static_file,view,template,post,request

app = Bottle()
print str(dir(app))
@app.route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static')

@app.route('/') 
def index(): 
        return template('template',text='This is index page!')
```

`template.tpl`:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/prettify.css" />
</head>
<body>
{{text}}
</body>

</html>
```

**Directory Listing**

```
temp/
  adapter.wsgi
  index.py
  routes.py
  static/
     prettify.css
  views/
     template.tpl
```

My issue is whenever I try to access the Bottle app using `http://192.168.1.3/temp` the webpage shows up without the static files, but whenever i access `http://192.168.1.3/temp/` [Please note the extra `/`] the page loads properly. What modification should I do such that the result of both 
`http://192.168.1.3/temp` and `http://192.168.1.3/temp/` become the same?

Any help would be highly helpful

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## The Problem

The problematic line is this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/prettify.css" />
```

The address of the CSS file is a relative one, thus the full absolute address is computed from the loaded page location.

For `http://192.168.1.3/temp/`, it will be `http://192.168.1.3/temp/static/prettify.css` (correct).

For `http://192.168.1.3/temp`, it will be `http://192.168.1.3/static/prettify.css`. `temp` is considered to be a file in the root directory, not a subdirectory of its own right.

## The Solution

There is no viable way to use a single relative address for referring to the static resources. Your application will likely to have “nested” paths like `/article/some-name`, or `/view/content/566`, or something like this, as well as paths as simple as `/`.

You can try to specify a root-based path, like `/temp/static/prettify.css`, in your template, but this means you will have to change the template if you relocate the app itself (say, to `myapp.example.com/` from  `example.com/myapp/`).

Instead, you need to tell the framework to make the correct path to the resource you need to use. Bottle has a function named [get_url](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.get_url) to facilitate this. Unfortunately, it's not mentioned in the Bottle tutorials.

## The Code

Here's what you should do.

In `template.tpl`, call `get_url` referring to the static handler:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="{{ get_url('static', filename='prettify.css') }}" />
```

In `routes.py`, import `get_url`:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, route, static_file, view, template, 
                   post, request, get_url
```

Then, name your handler so you can pass its name to `get_url`:

```
@app.route('/static/<filename>', name='static')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static')
```

Finally, supply the actual `get_url` as the template argument when rendering the template:

```
@app.route('/') 
def index(): 
    return template('template', text='This is index page!', get_url=get_url)
```

Alternatively, instead of supplying `get_url` in every handler, set up a template default in `index.py`:

```
from Bottle import SimpleTemplate
SimpleTemplate.defaults["get_url"] = app.get_url
```

**Caveat**: The last method seems to be undocumented, but was [explained by the Bottle's author on the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/bottlepy/browse_frm/thread/2f5cc0bbbd6d8287).

## Final Thought

As every page on a website should have a canonical address, you might want to choose one form (either with a trailing slash or without one) as canonical, and add some kind of redirect from the other one.

Comment: I've followed the steps here, and I'm getting a "NameError: name 'get_url' is not defined" when the stylesheet href attribute is being processed.  What could I be missing?  Thanks.

Comment: @Shawn: You should either supply it as a template argument (`get_url=get_url` in the call to `template`), or set a template default (`SimpleTemplate.defaults["get_url"] = app.get_url`). If you did it, and the error remains, I suggest that you create a new question with the excerpts from your code, and post a link here.

Comment: Thanks.  I did both, still got the error, and just trying something else, wrote get_url = app.get_url.  That worked, or at least the error has gone away and the app will actually load.  Now I've got to figure out why my css isn't getting loaded.  Thanks.

Comment: I just asked a question regarding this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885429/static-files-in-bottle-application.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: from bottle import get_url .... 

I get the error "Cannot import name get_url".  Also, the api docs for 0.11 (recent version as of today) shows get_url highlighted in yellow.  I assume that means it is no longer supported.

Comment: @G.A.: `get_url` is still available as a method of the `Bottle` class, and you should better create an app explicitly, anyway. See also http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#default-app

Comment: Upvote for `SimpleTemplate.defaults["get_url"] = app.get_url`. Made my day

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to add this redirection in your Apache configuration file :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(temp)$ /$1/
```

This will add a / at the end of your index page, so you don't have to modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to add:

```
<base href="/temp/">
```

to the head in the template.