# Static files in a Bottle application cannot be found (404)

Tags: python, bottle

I've reviewed all the questions here about this, reviewed the bottle tutorial, reviewed the bottle google group discussions, and AFAIK, I'm doing everything right.  Somehow, though, I can't get my CSS file to load properly.  I'm getting a 404 on the static file, that `http://localhost:8888/todo/static/style.css` is not found, which, according to the directory structure below, should not be the case.  I'm using version 0.11 (unstable) of Bottle; is there anything I'm missing, or is this a bug in Bottle?

My directory structure:

```
todo/
   todo.py
   static/
      style.css
```

My todo.py:

```
import sqlite3
from bottle import Bottle, route, run, debug, template, request, validate, static_file, error, SimpleTemplate

# only needed when you run Bottle on mod_wsgi
from bottle import default_app
app = Bottle()
default_app.push(app)

appPath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/todo/'


@app.route('/todo')
def todo_list():

    conn = sqlite3.connect(appPath + 'todo.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT id, task FROM todo WHERE status LIKE '1';")
    result = c.fetchall()
    c.close()

    output = template(appPath + 'make_table', rows=result, get_url=app.get_url)
    return output

@route('/static/:filename#.*#', name='css')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static')
```

My html:

```
%#template to generate a HTML table from a list of tuples (or list of lists, or tuple of tuples or ...)
<head>
<link href="{{ get_url('css', filename='style.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<p>The open items are as follows:</p>
<table border="1">
%for row in rows:
  <tr style="margin:15px;">
  %i = 0
  %for col in row:
    %if i == 0:
        <td>{{col}}</td>
    %else:
        <td>{{col}}</td>
    %end
    %i = i + 1
  %end
  <td><a href="/todo/edit/{{row[0]}}">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
%end
</table>
```

Comment: I had a lot of problems too. Can you show the GET as it appears in the console?

Comment: Simply "GET http://localhost:8888/todo/static/style.css 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: You have todo/ todo.py static/ style.css. Try with todo/static/style.css. It appears that your dir structure doesn't match the pgm.

Comment: @ f p  Try where?  I tried todo/static/style.css in the html, and got a 404 for todo/static/todo/static/style.css.

Comment: Where is the file on your disk?

Comment: @fp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/todo/static/style.css  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs is my localhost root.

Comment: Is that the same as your current folder? If it is try root='./todo/static'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12121/discussion-between-shawn-and-f-p)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't quite understand your deployment. The `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` path, along with the lack of `app.run` in your code, suggest that you're running this under Apache. Is it a production deployment? For dev tasks you are supposed to use Bottle's built-in dev server, you know. Add a single `app.run()` towards the end of your `todo.py`, and you're done.

Now if you are using Apache, the most probably root cause is this line: `static_file(filename, root='./static')`. With mod_wsgi, you are not guaranteed that the working directory is equal to the directory where your `todo.py` is placed. In fact, it will almost never be.

You are using absolute paths for the database and the template, do so for the static files:

```
@route('/static/:filename#.*#', name='css')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root=os.path.join(appPath, 'static'))
```

Next, I don't understand where your app is mounted. The URL `http://localhost:8888/todo/static/style.css` suggests that the mount point is `/todo`, but the route for the `todo_list` handler is again `/todo`. Is the full path supposed to be `http://localhost/todo/todo`? Does your app have a `/` handler?

I'd also suggest to avoid hard-coding paths and concat'ing the path fragments together. This would be cleaner:

```
from os.path import join, dirname
...
appPath = dirname(__file__)

@app.route('/todo')
def todo_list():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(join(appPath, 'todo.db'))
    ...
```

Comment: My deployment is in development against the MAMP apache stack using mod_wsgi.  I was able to get things working against Bottle's dev server; now I'm trying to develop against how I'll roll out the production, which is what's causing the problem.  I'll try the join instead of the concatenation.  localhost:8888 is the apache root.  There is a todo folder, which is where the todo.py code is stored.  The path is localhost:8888/todo/todo, which is confusing but works while I'm testing, though I haven't added a "/" handler.  I don't actually plan a todo app :-)

Comment: @Shawn: Ah, I see now. The Bottle dev server usually has the current directory correct, so this problem is rarely exposed. `join` is good, but what's really important is the absolute (think `appPath`) path passed to the `static_file`.

Comment: How do I determine at run time what the absolute path is?  My web inspector shows that the css files is being search for at /todo/static/style.css, which would be correct if the absolute path follows the /MAMP/htdocs/...  If not, of course it won't find it (though I'm still confused as to why the 404 path looks proper).

Comment: @Shawn: Just to clarify: as far as I understood your comment, `/todo/static/style.css` is the URL part, and `/Applications/MAMP/...` is the filesystem path. You must be confusing these two things.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it had nothing to do with Bottle and everything to do with my wsgi file that loaded the application.  I did not change my os.path to the correct path; it was pointing to the folder where the wsgi script was located.  Obviously, there was no css file there.  Once I corrected my directory in the sgi script, everything worked.  In other words:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

needed to be

```
os.chdir('Applications/MAMP/htdocs/todo')
```

because my wsgi script was in a different directory than the application itself (mod_wsgi recommends this approach).  Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: `os.chdir` is recommended, but not enough. The CWD can change anytime, you shouldn't rely on it. Provide the full path to your static files inside `server_static`, as I suggested.