# initializr with bottlepy - css not loaded

Tags: python, url-routing, bottle, static-files, initializr

I'm trying to use a boilerplate I downloaded from [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) together with bottle.py. I'm obviously doing something wrong since when I simply try to load `index.html` the site renders without using any of the stylesheets and I get the following errors in the browser console:

```
Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. requestNotifier.js:52
The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/css/normalize.min.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". localhost:8080
The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/css/main.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". localhost:8080
SyntaxError: syntax error modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js:1
SyntaxError: syntax error plugins.js:1
SyntaxError: syntax error
```

My app looks like this:

```
import bottle  # Web server
from bottle import run, route, static_file, error, template  # import request


@route('/')
def index():
    return static_file('index.html', root='./html/')

@route('./css/<filename>')
def server__static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./css/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # To run the server, type-in $ python server.py
    bottle.debug(True)  # display traceback
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```

The stylesheets are called from `index.html` like so:

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

My basic folder structure is (snipped js folder etc.):

```
bottle_test.py
- html
      index.html
      - css
           main.css
           normalize.min.css
```

I understand that [bottle doesn't serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543545/2488942) by itself and I did play around with the route to `server-static` and added, changed and removed the `mimetype` argument but can't get it to work.

The entire boilerplate sits in the `html` folder and the app does find `index.html`. I tried this in Firefox and Chrome. I'm on Win 8.1 and anaconda's python 2.7 if that matters. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paths seem wrong. The CSS route shouldn't start with a `.`, seems it interferes with how Bottle parses it. And your CSS `static_file` root doesn't properly reflect the `css` folder placement relative to the working directory.

This should work alright:

```
@route('/css/<filename>')
def server__static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./html/css')
```