# Bottle web app not serving static css files

Tags: python, bottle

My bottle web application is not serving my main.css file despite the fact I am using the static_file method.

app.py

```
from bottle import *
from xml.dom import minidom
@route('/')
def index():
    return template("index")

@route('/glossaryXML')
def glossary():
    doc_def = minidom.parse("table_definitions.xml")
    terms = doc_def.getElementsByTagName("str_term")
    defins = doc_def.getElementsByTagName("str_definition")
    return template("list", terms=terms, defins=defins)

@route('<filename>.css')
def stylesheets(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static')

@error(404)
def fourofour(error):
    return "Error"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The page I am trying to access is the index page, in which index.tpl looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ICT Applications Glossary</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        It works
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS file is located in a folder named "static" which is in my root folder

Comment: Check my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45761391/3129414

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead specify your static route like this

```
@route('/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static/')
```

This will serve any file in your static directory though not just css.

To make it stylesheet specific

```
@get('/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def stylesheets(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static/')
```

**Note:** for the latter option you could put stylesheets in their own directory 'static/css' or just 'css' and keep them separate from other static resources (scripts, images etc.) to do this just specify the `root` parameter to be that directory e.g. `root='static/css'.

Comment: This does route the CSS but it's still not being applied to my page

Comment: Sorry I had thought you would reference your style sheet as href="static/main.css" in the html. This is not the case. What is there now should be good.

Comment: When I refer to a page with the url "localhost:8080/category/<name>" the CSS that's being referenced is "category/static/main.css". Is there anyway I can change this to be the absolute path?

Comment: In your html link tag use an absolute address e.g. `<link type="text/css" href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems that I can see:

- The route for the CSS files should begin with a slash, ie.

  ```
  @route('/<filename>.css')
  ```
- Only the matching part of the pattern is passed to `stylesheets()` in
  the `filename` argument, e.g. instead of `main.css`, it will be
  `main`. Change the code to this:

  ```
  @route('/<filename>.css')
  def stylesheets(filename):
      return static_file('{}.css'.format(filename), root='static')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively... rename your **main.css** file to **main.tpl**, bookend with `<style>` and `</style>`, move it into the **/views** directory along with your other templates, then simply add to the beginning of your return line:

```
return (template ("main"), template ("list", terms=terms, defins=defins))
```