# Flask: Serve static files like css from different folder

Tags: python, flask

given a structure like inside a directory foo:

```
/web
    /static
        /css
        /img
/model
runapp.py
```

How to server static files from web/static/css or /img

like

```
<link href="{{ url_for('web/static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

It gives

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
BuildError: ('web/static', {'filename': 'css/bootstrap.min.css'}, None)
```

I have done

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'web','static'), static_url_path='')
```

but it doesn't work. and btw
whats the difference between static_folder and static_url_path ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358230/bottle-web-app-not-serving-static-css-files/29358366#29358366) any help?

Comment: `btw whats the difference between static_folder and static_url_path ?`. You can find the answers [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/)

Comment: @PaulRooney is it <path:filename> or <filename:path> because ver .10 shows the former pattern.

Answer (score 4):

`url_for('web/static')` won't work because `'static'` is a special blueprint for serving static files. So do this:

```
url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

And set the static folder in your app:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'web','static'))
```

`static_url_path` defaults to the name of `static_folder`. Not sure how setting it to `''` would help.